# Python Library Dependency graph

Tags: python, dependencies

I know other forms of this question exist and the one that looks the closest to what I am trying to do is here: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610155/tools-for-drawing-python-dependancy-graph/8611730#8611730).

However, what I am trying to do, is a library dependency tree for a Django project given a particular `requirements.txt` file that could contain pypi libs such as:

```
django-braces==1.1.0
```

...or could contain references to github like:

```
-e git+git@github.com:epicowl/django-chosen-ajax.git@fa51ad93e883cb22a0fe46135ddfd3c6e90b57fd#egg=django-chosen-ajax
```

I also want to be able to report what libraries those depend on as well (walking the tree).  I don't care about a call graph, only strictly dependencies.  It looks like most packages like snakefood do both module and library dependencies and I only care about libraries (and their versions) that are being included in the project.

I have the project in a virtualenv and can use pip freeze to find out all libraries that are installed, but does not show me where the dependencies are and also only gives me the SHA for the libs from github instead of a version number.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I have decided the best solution for this is to use pip freeze to get the list of parent libraries, then use yolk -d to determine the dependencies of each parent and build a dependency tree.  As far as the github entries, I am just parsing those strings to get the library name and using yolk -d.